# TypeError: date.toLocaleTimeString is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a time display component with hooks and I'm getting "TypeError: date.toLocaleTimeString is not a function." I'm very much a beginner to this so any help would be much appreciated. I've called the component of

```
<Time date={date} setDate={setDate}/>
```

in my main file and I've imported/exported Time properly. Here is my code from my Time.js file:

```
function Time(date, setDate) {
    //Replaces componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount
 useEffect(() => {
    var timerID = setInterval( () => tick(), 1000 );
  
    return function cleanup() {
        clearInterval(timerID);
      };
   });
  
     function tick() {
      setDate(new Date());
     }
     return (
        <div>
        <div className="test">1</div>
          <h2>It is {date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `date` is likely not a `Date` object at the time it first renders (it's probably undefined). Depends on how you call `Time`.

Comment: What is the initial value of `date`?

Comment: My apologies. I should have mentioned that I also declared
    `const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());`
in my main file as well. Therefore `date` should have the initial value of `Date()`?

Comment: Potentially the only issue here is that your `Time` component only takes one argument (props). You can destructure the props like so: `function Time({ date, setDate })`

Comment: I love you @Nick you're a beast

Comment: @JavierHernandez nice, just did an official answer if you want to give me that sweet upvote/answer reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React components only take one argument (props). You can use destructuring to pluck individual keys out of your props and the rest of your component will remain unchanged:

```js
function Time({ date, setDate }) {
  // `date` will now be a Date object as you expect
}
```